# Atualizar página insere novamente

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, aplicação-web

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento web com java e estou fazendo alguns testes e me deparei com a seguinte situação, criei um formulario que carrega uma lista baseado em todo clique do botão, porém, quando eu atualizo a página eu ainda carrego a lista com o ultimo objeto que foi inserido na lista. Deu para entender? Se sim, porque acontece isso?

EDIT Códigos.

Método que executa a inserção de aluno em uma lista.

```
    public void incluirAluno(){
    this.listaAlunos.add(aluno);
    System.out.println("Aluno: "+aluno.getNome()+" foi adicionado com sucesso!");           
    this.aluno = new Aluno();
}
```

View

```
<h:form>
        <p:fieldset legend="Formulário de Cadastro de Clientes" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">

        <b>Nome Completo    </b><br/>   
        <p:inputText value="#{controllerAluno.aluno.nome}" placeholder="Digite seu Nome Aqui" style="width:30%"/>                        
        <p></p>             
        <b>Data de Nascimento</b>   <br/>                            
        <p:calendar id="effect" value="#{controllerAluno.aluno.data_Nascimento}" effect="fold" placeholder="10/10/2010"/> 
        <p></p>             
        <b>Sexo</b><br/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="console"   value="#{controllerAluno.aluno.sexo}"  style="width:125px">        
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Masculino" itemValue="Masculino" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Feminino" itemValue="Feminino" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Indiferente" itemValue="Indiferente" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p></p>          
        <h:commandButton value="Incluir" action="#{controllerAluno.incluirAluno}"/>             
        <p></p>                                                                            
        </p:fieldset>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Adicione os trechos do código que contenham os métodos envolvidos, assim como sua view.

Answer (score 5):

Isso acontece porque você está submetendo a mesma requisição de inclusão ao atualizar a página. Isso é uma falha de segurança que deve ser tratada na arquitetura do teu sistema. Uma forma de tratar isso é adicionar um trecho de proteção contra F5 que invalida o estado de uma requisição submetida em um fluxo inválido. No seu caso você só precisaria verificar se o mesmo aluno está sendo inserido novamente e nesse caso bloquear a inserção. Um exemplo de como isso pode ser feito é:

```
public void incluirAluno(){
 if (isAlunoJaAdicionado(aluno) {
    addMensagemErro("O aluno selecionado já foi adicionado!");
    return;
 }
 this.listaAlunos.add(aluno);
 System.out.println("Aluno: "+aluno.getNome()+" foi adicionado com sucesso!");           
 this.aluno = new Aluno();
}

public boolean isAlunoJaAdicionado(Aluno aluno) {
  return this.listaAlunos.contains(aluno);
}
```

Para que o método contains identifique que o aluno já foi adicionado, é necessário que você implemente o método equals na tua classe aluno: Exemplo:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  return this.nome.equals(((Aluno) obj).getNome());
}
```

OBS: O addMensagemErro seria implementado conforme o mecanismo de mensagens que você estiver usando. Exemplo com JSF:

```
public void addMensagemErro(String mensagem) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, mensagem, null);
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```